# Passing java.sql.Date to sql query

Tags: jdbc

This is a part of my code

```
java.sql.Date d1=java.sql.Date.valueOf("2011-03-02"); 
java.sql.Date d2=java.sql.Date.valueOf("2011-03-10"); 
java.sql.Date systemDate=java.sql.Date.valueOf("2011-03-04");

String sql="select id from period where '"+systemDate+"' between '"+d1+"' and '"+d2+"'";
```

This is my code. I want to get the id which falls between these dates. But i am not getting the desired result. I am getting back all the id present in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have good results when you use other SQL tools (like pgadmin for PostgreSQL or SQL Developer for Oracle)?

Is so then try to use [PreparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). In your case this will look like:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select id from period where ? between ? and ?");
pstmt.setDate(1, systemDate);
pstmt.setDate(2, d1);
pstmt.setDate(3, d2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using a field from your table to compare with your date range.

What you're doing is checking if 04-03-2011 is between 02-03-2011 and 10-03-2011, which is true for every record.

What you want to do is something like this (assuming start_date is a column in your table):

```
  String sql="select id from period where start_date between '"+d1+"' and '"+d2+"'";
```

(Also, I agree with the answer above that prepared statements are a better way to construct queries.)